# Was the Sheiltot of Rav Achai Gaon ever translated?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, english, geonim

Does anyone know if the Sheiltot was ever translated into English?

Comment: I believe it was not, though excerpts of it are sporadically mentioned in English in Louis Ginzberg’s ‘Geonica’.